# Laptop heats up faster and much more

Tags: battery

I've installed Ubuntu (14.0.4 LTS) recently and my laptop is heating up more than ever...
I am not even getting more time on battery.
My PC is a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 (3rd gen, ci5 , 4gb, 128gb ssd)

Comment: Could you please use the following command in a terminal window: 'top' (without any quotes) and post the first process name which is on top and uses the most CPU %

Comment: There's cooling pads on amazon, but I'd suggest opening your laptop up, and adding some thermal paste to the cpu.

Comment: @Serg I don't think he has to open his laptop when he stated that it's heating more than ever so i suggest he didn't have the heat problem before Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your BIOS and disable the NVIDIA GPU. For Lenovo, change from Optimus to UMA.